# An expected CSRF token cannot be found error in WebSecurity Spring Boot 3.1.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

Im recieving an error: "An expected CSRF token cannot be found" when testing with Postman to register a user in my app. The plan is to register a user & confirm the email address. Although when testing the app it runs although when the endpoint is tested it would throw the An expected CSRF token cannot be found error in Postman.

Issue also persists when there is .csrf().disable() added in the code in WebSecurityConfig.

**Request which is being sent in Body in Postman**

`localhost:8090/api/v1/registration

{
"firstName": "Ali",
"lastName": "Ali",
"email": "nilerumi@socam.me",
"password": "password"
}`

Could you advise why I would be getting such error?

Here are the classes:

**Registration Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/registration")
public class RegistrationController {

    private final RegistrationService registrationService;

    @Autowired
    public RegistrationController(RegistrationService registrationService) {
        this.registrationService = registrationService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
        return registrationService.register(request);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "confirm")
    public String confirm(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        return registrationService.confirmToken(token);
    }
}
```

**Registration Service**

```
@Service
public class RegistrationService {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private final EmailValidator emailValidator;
    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmTokenService;
    private final EmailSender emailSender;


    public RegistrationService(AppUserService appUserService, EmailValidator emailValidator, ConfirmationTokenService confirmTokenService, EmailSender emailSender) {
        this.appUserService = appUserService;
        this.emailValidator = emailValidator;
        this.confirmTokenService = confirmTokenService;
        this.emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    public String register(RegistrationRequest request) {
        boolean isValidEmail = emailValidator.test(request.getEmail());
        if (isValidEmail) {
            String tokenForNewUser = appUserService.signUpUser(new AppUser(request.getFirstName(),
                    request.getLastName(),
                    request.getEmail(),
                    request.getPassword(),
                    AppUserRole.USER));

            //Since, we are running the spring boot application in localhost, we are hardcoding the
            //url of the server. We are creating a POST request with token param
            String link = "http://localhost:8090/api/v1/registration/confirm?token=" + tokenForNewUser;
            emailSender.sendEmail(request.getEmail(), buildEmail(request.getFirstName(), link));
            return tokenForNewUser;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Email %s, not valid", request.getEmail()));
        }
    }


    @Transactional
    public String confirmToken(String token) {
        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = confirmTokenService
                .getToken(token)
                .orElseThrow(() ->
                        new IllegalStateException("Token Not Found"));

        if (confirmationToken.getConfirmedAt() != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email Already Confirmed");
        }

        LocalDateTime expiredAt = confirmationToken.getExpiresAt();

        if (expiredAt.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("token expired");
        }

        confirmTokenService.setConfirmedAt(token);
        appUserService.enableAppUser(
                confirmationToken.getAppUser().getEmail());
        return "confirmed";
    }

    private String buildEmail(String name, String link) {
        return "<div style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;margin:0;color:#0b0c0c\">\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<span style=\"display:none;font-size:1px;color:#fff;max-height:0\"></span>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "  <table role=\"presentation\" width=\"100%\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;min-width:100%;width:100%!important\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">\n" +
                "    <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"100%\" height=\"53\" bgcolor=\"#0b0c0c\">\n" +
                "        \n" +
                "        <table role=\"presentation\" width=\"100%\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;max-width:580px\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\">\n" +
                "          <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "            <td width=\"70\" bgcolor=\"#0b0c0c\" valign=\"middle\">\n" +
                "                <table role=\"presentation\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse\">\n" +
                "                  <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "                    <td style=\"padding-left:10px\">\n" +
                "                  \n" +
                "                    </td>\n" +
                "                    <td style=\"font-size:28px;line-height:1.315789474;Margin-top:4px;padding-left:10px\">\n" +
                "                      <span style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:700;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:top;display:inline-block\">Confirm your email</span>\n" +
                "                    </td>\n" +
                "                  </tr>\n" +
                "                </tbody></table>\n" +
                "              </a>\n" +
                "            </td>\n" +
                "          </tr>\n" +
                "        </tbody></table>\n" +
                "        \n" +
                "      </td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "  </tbody></table>\n" +
                "  <table role=\"presentation\" class=\"m_-6186904992287805515content\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;max-width:580px;width:100%!important\" width=\"100%\">\n" +
                "    <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"10\" height=\"10\" valign=\"middle\"></td>\n" +
                "      <td>\n" +
                "        \n" +
                "                <table role=\"presentation\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse\">\n" +
                "                  <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "                    <td bgcolor=\"#1D70B8\" width=\"100%\" height=\"10\"></td>\n" +
                "                  </tr>\n" +
                "                </tbody></table>\n" +
                "        \n" +
                "      </td>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"10\" valign=\"middle\" height=\"10\"></td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "  </tbody></table>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "  <table role=\"presentation\" class=\"m_-6186904992287805515content\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;max-width:580px;width:100%!important\" width=\"100%\">\n" +
                "    <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "      <td height=\"30\"><br></td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "    <tr>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"10\" valign=\"middle\"><br></td>\n" +
                "      <td style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:19px;line-height:1.315789474;max-width:560px\">\n" +
                "        \n" +
                "            <p style=\"Margin:0 0 20px 0;font-size:19px;line-height:25px;color:#0b0c0c\">Hi " + name + ",</p><p style=\"Margin:0 0 20px 0;font-size:19px;line-height:25px;color:#0b0c0c\"> Thank you for registering. Please click on the below link to activate your account: </p><blockquote style=\"Margin:0 0 20px 0;border-left:10px solid #b1b4b6;padding:15px 0 0.1px 15px;font-size:19px;line-height:25px\"><p style=\"Margin:0 0 20px 0;font-size:19px;line-height:25px;color:#0b0c0c\"> <a href=\"" + link + "\">Activate Now</a> </p></blockquote>\n Link will expire in 15 minutes. <p>See you soon</p>" +
                "        \n" +
                "      </td>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"10\" valign=\"middle\"><br></td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "    <tr>\n" +
                "      <td height=\"30\"><br></td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "  </tbody></table><div class=\"yj6qo\"></div><div class=\"adL\">\n" +
                "\n" +
                "</div></div>";
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())
                .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and()
                .formLogin();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);
        return provider;
    }

}
```

**Confirmation Token**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ConfirmationToken {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String token;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime expiresAt;

    private LocalDateTime confirmedAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false,
            name = "app_user_id")
    private AppUser appUser;

    public ConfirmationToken() {
    }

    public ConfirmationToken(String token, LocalDateTime createdAt, LocalDateTime expiresAt, AppUser appUser) {
        this.token = token;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.expiresAt = expiresAt;
        this.appUser = appUser;
    }
}
```

Have checked the pom.xml file seems ok with the dependencies
Have checked the application.yaml
In the current setup I had to use allow-bean-definition-overriding: true in yaml.

Comment: The fact that you need to allow the override is weird, that being said you shouldn't disable csrf as it adds security to your website. Get the CSRF token (you might need to configure seomthing to pass it as a cookie or header) and include it in your requests.